# Code search - exclude typings when searching for particular typescript function

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Suppose I do code search for `createPerformanceMarker` in all typescript filesin repo.
I use this search:

`createPerformanceMarker ext:ts`.

This unfortunately returns also typings (interface declaration files with extension `.d.ts`)

Ref:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/advanced-code-search-syntax?view=azure-devops

I tried several different formats, but they don't work (`createPerformanceMarker ext:ts NOT ext:d.ts` etc.)

Is there a way how to exclude typings when searching ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way how to exclude typings when searching ?

Indeed, just like you test, the combination format `ext:ts NOT ext:d.ts` is not work as expected.

More research found that **the filter will default to using the field after the last point `.` as the file extension to search** when we use `ext:`. That means that whether you use `ext:ts` or `ext:d.ts` to search, Code search will use `.ts` as a keyword for matching search. That is the reason why we use the search condition is `ext:ts NOT ext:d.ts` to search but got the result is `No. Code files found for 'ext:ts NOT ext:d.ts' with applied filters`.

To resolve this issue, I would like provide a solution for this situation. We could use the combination format **`ext:ts  NOT file:*.d`** to exclude typings `.d.ts`.

As test (For convenience I test it with `.ps1` file ) on my side:

[image]

Hope this helps.